# Calling functions with different numbers of arguments in Rust macros

Tags: macros, rust

I need a macro that will call functions with different numbers of arguments or a macro that will generate a valid argument list from its (repeating) parameters.

I am fine with explicitly giving the information about the number of arguments to the macro, but I can't figure out how to generate the argument list for the function - I always stumble on the macros returning expressions rather than token tree.

I made the following [playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=aae1deacf051ec4ef388ec93aa6c4123&version=stable):

```
macro_rules! call (
    ($f: expr, $($params:tt)*) => {
        $f(make_params!($($params:tt)*))
    };
);

macro_rules! make_params {
    () => {};
    (I $($params: tt)*) => {
        1, make_params!($($params:tt)*)
    };
}


fn foo(a: i32, b: i32, c: i32) {
    println!("foo: {} {} {}", a, b, c);
}

fn bar(a: i32, b: i32) {
    println!("bar: {} {}", a, b);
}

fn main() {
    call!(foo, I I I);
    call!(bar, I I);
}
```

The compiler complains with the following:

```
error: macro expansion ignores token `,` and any following
  --> src/main.rs:10:10
   |
10 |         1, make_params!($($params:tt)*)
   |          ^
   |
note: caused by the macro expansion here; the usage of `make_params!` is likely invalid in expression context
  --> src/main.rs:3:12
   |
3  |         $f(make_params!($($params:tt)*))
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...
```

How can I treat the return of `make_params!` as a token stream (or such) rather than expression?

My real use case is a bit more involved than this toy example. My functions have multiple parameter types which are constructed in different ways. In my case, just making macros `call1`, `call2!`, ... does not seem like a good solution, as I would need the likes of `call_IIOOI`, `call_IIIO`, etc.

Comment: A macro has to expend to a valid AST element. `1, foo` isn't a valid AST element.

Comment: @mcarton thanks! Oh well ... so with no direct way to construct an argument list, cna you see some other solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to build the function call progressively as you go and only emit it at once in the end:

```
macro_rules! call (
    ($f: expr, $($params:tt)*) => {
        make_call!($f, () $($params)*)
    };
);

macro_rules! make_call {
    ($f: expr, ($($args:tt)*)) => { $f($($args)*) };
    ($f: expr, () I $($params:tt)*) => {
        make_call!($f, (1) $($params)*)
    };
    ($f: expr, ($($args:tt)*) I $($params:tt)*) => {
        make_call!($f, ($($args)*, 1) $($params)*)
    };
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f3e92fc1251eceeea9ff94a2614b0814&version=stable)

Comment: I see this uses an accumulator to construct the parameter list. I was wondering about something in that direction but didn't see how  to do it. This is more or less exactly what I needed - thanks!